# Android Sync Adapter Intervals

Tags: android

I require a data sync once per day for an Android application. I've been using Sync Adapter which has been very useful. I want to sync the data only once per day (at no specific time). I'm using the addPeriodicSync() method.

My problem is that users are only likely to enter an area with internet access for very short periods at different times of the day (sometimes not in internet access areas for days at a time). I have the sync interval at 1 day, will the sync process be run as soon as the internet becomes available? or will it only attempt to sync when the period sync timer is triggered?

Additionally, are there any options to enable/disable 3G/Mobile internet syncs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes by design sync adapters will queue all sync request in absence of network , also if user asks for manual sync when auto sync is already in queue then it will handle it . That's the beauty of sync adapter design